# How to refer to an object created by "with" within the construct?

Tags: vb.net

I often use `with` to create an object and run its methods.  it makes the code look clean:

```
With New MyObj(...)
  .Prop1 = Val1
  .Prop2 = Val2
  .Run()
End With
```

however, sometimes I'd like to return the object:

```
With New MyObj(...)
  .Prop1 = Val1
  .Prop2 = Val2
  Return .Me
End With
```

but not all objects have a Me (this) property, so how can I refer to the object in question within the `with`?

Comment: You could assign the object to a variable before using the With statement, then return the object outside the block.

Comment: Are you are looking for the VB.NET equivalent of C# `return new MyObj() { Prop1 = X, Prop2 = Y };`?

Comment: Actually `.Me` is something I've never seen on any object, so had to create one myself for one of my custom classes. VB.NET should have had the `.` syntax, which would refer to the current With block variable. So it would be `Return .`. Unfortunately, does not work like that. You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256776/is-there-a-way-to-debug-vb-net-with-clause-in-visual-studio) interesting.

Comment: @Neolisk, haha.  yes, I did try `Return .` but of course, it doesn't compile

Comment: @ekkis: No, unfortunately. I tried that too the first time I needed it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I guess the answer is that so long as I can change the definition of the object in question I can do this:

```
Public Class XC
    Public Self As XC = Me
End Class

With New XC()
  Dim x As XC = .Self
End With
```

Comment: It is nice but it seems that more fair answer to your original question is: It is not possible.

Comment: @IvanH, it is absolutely possible.  just do: `With New XC(); Return .Self; End With`

Comment: OK. I was not precise: It is not possible when you are not allowed to change the object definition. However in most cases I A not really allowed to do it. And to add special method to all classes is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I would retain a reference to the instance before starting the `With` block, then `Return` it after you're done using the members:

```
Dim myInstance = New MyObj(...)
With myInstance
  .Prop1 = Val1
  .Prop2 = Val2
End With
Return myInstance
```

You don't need to worry about garbage collection implications, since the variable you are creating goes out of scope once you return anyway.

Comment: yes, I realise I could do that.  I was hoping there was a way to refer to the object within the `With` construct

Comment: @ekkis What is the disadvantage to doing it this way?

Comment: @Asad: you are repeating the variable name 3 times.

Comment: @Asad, it's just not as clean

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VB object initializer syntax with Option Infer:

```
Dim variable As New SomeClass With
{
    .AString = "Hello",
    .AnInteger = 12345
}
return variable
```

You still have a variable, but it's pretty clean.

If you don't want the variable you might try code like this:

```
Return New SomeClass With
{
    .AString = "Hello",
    .AnInteger = 12345
}
```

I don't believe this syntax allows you to call methods on the instance, however.  I think you can only set properties.