# How can an object refer to itself?

Tags: vb.net

in Javascript every object carries a `this` which refers to itself.  How can a field in a class be created to refer to the object that contains it?

**- addendum -**

to clarify, what I mean is that if I declare:

```
Class xc
  Private i As Integer
End Class
```

and then make the reference:

```
Dim x As New xc()
x.Me
```

I get the error:

> 'Me' is not a member of
>   'MyProject.xc'. - \x...\test.vb(3)
>   - Source Line: x.Me

incidentally, the question arises from the following, related question: [How to refer to an object created by "with" within the construct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572018/how-to-refer-to-an-object-created-by-with-within-the-construct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha.  this seems to work.

```
Public Class XC
    Public Self As XC = Me
End Class

Dim x As New XC()
Dim y As XC = x.Self
```

Answer (score 4):

VB.NET has the `Me` keyword.

```
Me.Name = "Name"
```

Comment: Isn't that "Me" is refer to form ?

Comment: If you are in an instance method, then Me refers to the current class instance.  @matzone, if you are in a form, then the class would be the derived form class.

Comment: my question refers to any class.  when you define a class it doesn't automatically come with a `Me` so I'm wondering how to create one

Comment: You don't need to create one. If you're in an instance of a class Me is just there, but it refers to the class you are in. In a Form you are in an instance of a form, so it's there. In a custom object you are in an instance of it, so it's there.

Answer (score 2):

`This` is `Me` in Visual Basic.

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub test()
        MsgBox(Me.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0.aspx

Comment: Maybe because MsgBox is not really a .NET function.

Comment: `Me` is not present in all classes

Comment: @ekkis, can you give a sample when it is not available?

Comment: I added a link. `Me` is not present in "all classes", it is present in every _instance_ of a class.

Comment: I think @ekkis just needs to post the specific situation where Me isn't meeting his needs.

Comment: @MikeCole, class xc end class; dim x as new xc(); x.Me -- I'm asking this question with respect to different issue.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572018/how-to-refer-to-an-object-created-by-with-within-the-construct

Comment: Well, you are right in that other thread, `Me` cannot be used on objects like `this` as if it were a member. It is a basic language keyword that always refers to the object where the code is currently executed. It would sometimes be neat to refer to the object itself within a with block, I agree, but that simply doesn't work in VB.

Comment: Could a person use reflection to get a reference to the current instance of the class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refer to instance of class, because your instance is a reference.
So your code `x.Me` will be just `x`.

Me(VB.NET) or this(C#) are reference to instance of class only inside of this instance

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173109.aspx):

> A class is a reference type. When an object of the class is created,
>   the variable to which the object is assigned holds only a reference to
>   that memory.

But if your realy want to have a memeber of class, then just create a memeber of type of your class and assign it like this:

```
Public MyPreference as YourClass
```

and then assign it

```
Me.MyReference = Me
```